# Strange characters in one xml file but not in the other from webAPI

Tags: android

I'm having a strange problem, I'm working with an app that downloads series information from thetvdb.com and I'm having problems with "strange" characters. I am using two diffrent xml-files from their server, the first being their search method:

http://www.thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=100

This is displaying å,ä and ö as it should, however when using the details xml I'm getting strange characters: http://www.thetvdb.com/data/series/80026/all/

I've looked at them both in my webbrowser and they both return UTF-8. I have tried lots of the tips I've found online but nothing works.

I'm at work so I cant find them all but the type of characters I'm getting is:  "Ã¶" and "Ã¤"

Comment: Strange characters like what?  Can you copy / paste them into the question?

Comment: I've edited the original post

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the problem, but I belive that it's not the solution to the real problem. I'm using EntityUtils.toString and i hadn't specified encoding, after adding the "UTF8" as the defaultCharset parameter problem was solved. But the real problem must be with the xml file but i just can't figure out what! :)